# setting the value of asp.net dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using a rad window and opening that window it has a asp.net drop down list. On page load I want to set the selected index of drop down but it always shows me default value.

```
<telerik:RadWindow runat="server" 
         OnClientClose="ParentReload"
         OpenerElementID="<%# btn_ChangeLocation.ClientID %>"
         Width="400px" Height="205px" ID="RadWindow1">
</telerik:RadWindow>
```

Comment: Don't you think we need a little more than this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `SelectedIndex` property?

```
[YourDropDown].SelectedIndex = [YourDesiredIndex];
```

Comment: I am having asp.netdrop down list

Comment: @Dharm, the property is the same. If you've attempted to set it and it didn't work, post your code.